# How would I distinct my list of key/value pairs

Tags: c#, linq, list

If I have a list `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`ex.

```
["abc","123"]
["asc","123"]
["asdgf","123"]
["abc","123"]
```

how can I distinc this list?

Comment: Distinct by Key, by Value or by both?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary` rather than a `List`?

Comment: Dictionary is not a good answer: Does not distinct by value or by both AND gives you duplicate key exceptions before distinctin' it ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Distinct by both `Key` and `Value`:

```
var results = source.Distinct().ToList();
```

Distinct by `Key` or `Value` (just change the property on `GroupBy` call:

```
var results = source.GroupBy(x => x.Key).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a Set (of pair objects) if you wish to have distinct pairs or a Map/Dictionary if you wish to have distinct keys.

Comment: Does .NET have a proper Set collection?

Comment: `ISet<T>` is the interface, and `HashSet<T>` is an implementation. Works as expected.

Comment: The other usual `ISet<>` being `SortedSet<>`. Edit: Although the `SortedSet<KeyValuePair<,>>` is only useful if given an `IComparer<>` when constructed.

Comment: My answer was answering the correct collection type that suits his need (no repeated items), the actual implementation of this collection type would depend on how he's going to use it which we don't know!