# Remove duplicates in custom IComparable class

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that has combo pairs identifiers, and I use that to go through CSV files looking for matches. I'm trapping the unidentified pairs in a List, and sending them to an output box for later addition. I would like the output to only have single occurrences of unique pairs. The class is declared as follows:

```
    public class Unmatched:IComparable<Unmatched>
{
    public string first_code { get; set; }
    public string second_code { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Unmatched other)
    {

        if (this.first_code == other.first_code)
        {
            return this.second_code.CompareTo(other.second_code);
        }

        return other.first_code.CompareTo(this.first_code);
    }
 }
```

One note on the above code: This returns it in reverse alphabetical order, to get it in alphabetical order use this line:

```
return this.first_code.CompareTo(other.first_code);
```

Here is the code that adds it. This is directly after the comparison against the datatable elements

```
unmatched.Add(new Unmatched() 
{ first_code = fields[clients[global_index].first_match_column]
, second_code = fields[clients[global_index].second_match_column] });
```

I would like to remove all pairs from the list where both first code and second code are equal, i.e.;

```
PTC,138A
PTC,138A
PTC,138A
MA9,5A
MA9,5A
MA9,5A
MA63,138A
MA63,138A
MA59,87BM
MA59,87BM
```

Should become:

```
PTC, 138A
MA9, 5A
MA63, 138A
MA59, 87BM
```

I have tried adding my own Equate and GetHashCode as outlined here:
http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/01/Use-of-Distinct-with-Custom-Class-objects-in-C-Sharp.html

The SE links I have tried are here:

[How would I distinct my list of key/value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955886/how-would-i-distinct-my-list-of-key-value-pairs)

[Get list of distinct values in List<T> in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810047/get-list-of-distinct-values-in-listt-in-c-sharp)

[Get a list of distinct values in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255121/get-list-of-distinct-values-in-listfoo)

All of them return a list that still has all the pairs. Here is the current code (Yes, I know there are two distinct lines, neither appears to be working) that outputs the list:

```
    parser.Close();
    List<Unmatched> noDupes = unmatched.Distinct().ToList();
    noDupes.Sort();
    noDupes.Select(x => x.first_code).Distinct();

    foreach (var pair in noDupes)
    {
        txtUnmatchedList.AppendText(pair.first_code + "," + pair.second_code + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Here is the Equate/Hash code as requested:

```
public bool Equals(Unmatched notmatched)
{

    //Check whether the compared object is null.  
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(notmatched, null)) return false;

    //Check whether the compared object references the same data.  
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, notmatched)) return true;

    //Check whether the UserDetails' properties are equal.  
    return first_code.Equals(notmatched.first_code) && second_code.Equals(notmatched.second_code);
}

// If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects   
// then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.  

public override int GetHashCode()
{

    //Get hash code for the UserName field if it is not null.  
    int hashfirst_code = first_code == null ? 0 : first_code.GetHashCode();

    //Get hash code for the City field.  
    int hashsecond_code = second_code.GetHashCode();

    //Calculate the hash code for the GPOPolicy.  
    return hashfirst_code ^ hashsecond_code;
}
```

I have also looked at a couple of answers that are using queries and Tuples, which I honestly don't understand. Can someone point me to a source or answer that will explain the how (And why) of getting distinct pairs out of a custom list?

(Side question-Can you declare a class as both IComparable and IEquatable?)

Comment: It seems like you have a formatting issue here. I can't see why `unmatched.Distinct().ToList()` would return duplicates otherwise. Are you sure that the strings are actually equal?

Comment: Please add your definition of `Equals` and `GetHashcode` since these are used for finding duplicates, not your `IComparable<T>` implementation. And yes a class can implement both `IComparable<T>` and `IEquatable<T>`.

Comment: While the first `Distinct()` should already do the job, please be aware that `noDupes.Select(x => x.first_code).Distinct();` does not have any effect, as you are throwing away the result.

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo - I added the code that inserts the pairs into the list.

Comment: Also, is it intentional that in the expected result, there is some whitespace after the comma, whereas in the original input, there is none?

Comment: As for the side-question, yes, you can implement any number of interfaces in a class.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - I added the hash and equals code, but how do you implement multiple interfaces? Just a comma and the second reference?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - When I tried to assign the second comparison (x =>) to a list, it was giving me a conversion error.

Comment: @JohnP: Yes, see [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4taxa8t2.aspx).

Comment: @JohnP: Yes, because `Distinct()` returns an `IEnumerable`, not a list (cf. [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Hence the conversion error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are not implementing `IEquatable<Unmatched>`.

```
public class Unmatched : IComparable<Unmatched>, IEquatable<Unmatched>
```

`EqualityComparer<T>.Default` uses the `Equals(T)` method only if you implement `IEquatable<T>`. You are not doing this, so it will instead use `Object.Equals(object)` which uses reference equality.

The overload of `Distinct` you are calling uses [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) to compare different elements of the sequence for equality. As the documentation states, the returned comparer uses your implementation of `GetHashCode` to find potentially-equal elements. It then uses the `Equals(T)` method to check for equality, or `Object.Equals(Object)` if you have not implemented `IEquatable<T>`.

You have an `Equals(Unmatched)` method, but it will not be used since you are not implementing `IEquatable<Unmatched>`. Instead, the default `Object.Equals` method is used which uses reference equality.

Note your current `Equals` method is not overriding `Object.Equals` since that takes an `Object` parameter, and you would need to specify the `override` modifier.

Comment: So, I need to change Unmatched:IComparable<Unmatched> to Unmatched:IComparable<Unmatched>, IEquatable<Unmatched>? Do I need to leave in the Hash and Equate overrides?

Comment: @JohnP - Yes you need to keep the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. Note your current `Equals` implementation is not an override of `Object.Equals`, since that takes an `Object` parameter.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I basically cut/pasted/replaced out of the blog link for the Equate and the Hash overrides.

Comment: I added the IEquatable declaration and voila. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

For an example on using Distinct see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You have to implement the `IEqualityComparer<TSource>` and not `IComparable<TSource>`.